# Applying lambda functions with updated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Let us assume we are given the below function:

```
def f(x,y):
    y = x + y
    return y
```

The function `f(x,y)` sums two numbers (but it could be any more or less complicated functions of two arguments). Let us now consider the following

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame({'first': random.sample(range(0, 9), 5),
                   'second': np.NaN}, index = None)
y = 1

df
   first  second
0      7     NaN
1      1     NaN
2      0     NaN
3      6     NaN
4      4     NaN
```

for the scope of the question the second column of the data frame is here irrelevant, so we can without loss of generality assume it to be `NaN`. Let us apply `f(x,y)` to each row of the data frame, considering that the variable `y` has been initialised to 1. The first iteration returns 7+1 = 8; now, when applying the function again to second row, we want the `y` value to be updated to the previously calculated 8 and therefore the final result to be 1+8 =9, and so on and so forth.

What is the pythonic way to handle this? I want to avoid looping and re-assigning the variables inside the loop, thus my guess would be something along the lines of

```
def apply_to_df(df, y):
    result = df['first'].apply(lambda s: f(s,y))
    return result
```

however one may easily see that the above does not consider the updated values, whereas it computes the all calculations with the initial original value for `y=1`.

```
print(apply_to_df(df,y))
0    8
1    2
2    1
3    7
4    5
```

Comment: What you're describing is a recurrence relation.  There is no built-in way to do this in pandas, although it's been discussed and there is an open (but old) [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4567) about it.  Right now, you have to loop in order to do it.

Comment: Is this not a cumsum(), or a reduce more generally?

Comment: In this case, it appears to be: `df['first'].cumsum() + y0` where `y0` is the initial seed value for y (1 in this example).

Comment: The example may be a little unfortunate as it can actually be solve using a cumulative sum; however, the actual question regards any more or less complicated function of two (or any) variables.

Answer (score 2):

Note, you can probably solve this *specific* case with an existing cumulative function. However, in the general case, you could just hack it by relying on global state:

```
In [7]: y = 1

In [8]: def f(x):
   ...:     global y
   ...:     y = x + y
   ...:     return y
   ...:

In [9]: df['first'].apply(lambda s: f(s))
Out[9]:
0     8
1     9
2     9
3    15
4    19
Name: first, dtype: int64
```

> I want to avoid looping and re-assigning the variables inside the loop

Note, `pd.DataFrame.apply` *is* a vanilla Python loop under the hood, and it's actually less efficient because it does a lot of checking/validation of inputs. It is not meant to be efficient, but convenient. So if you care about performance, you've already given up if you are relying on `.apply`

Honestly, I think I would rather write the explicit loop over the rows inside of a function than rely on global state.

Comment: The trick of the global variable actually works, although as you mentioned I would then just consider make the whole loop just more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator function to remember the prior calculation result:

```
def my_generator(series, foo, y_seed=0):
    y = y_seed  # Seed value for `y`.
    s = series.__iter__()  # Create an iterator on the series.
    while True:
        # Call the function on the next `x` value together with the most recent `y` value.
        y = foo(x=s.next(), y=y)   
        yield y

df = df.assign(new_col=list(my_generator(series=df['first'], foo=f, y_seed=1)))
>>> df
   first  second  new_col
0      8     NaN        9
1      3     NaN       12
2      0     NaN       12
3      5     NaN       17
4      4     NaN       21
```